# string to numbers (vector array of int type)conversion

Tags: c++, c++14

The function takes a string containing of comma(,) separated numbers as string and converts into numbers. Sometimes it produces a garbage value at the end.

```
vector<int> parseInts(string str)
 {
  int as[200]={0};
  int i=0,j=0;
  for(;str[i]!='\0';i++)
  {  
     while(str[i]!=','&&str[i]!='\0')
      {as[j]= as[j]*10 +str[i] -'0';
       i++;}
      j++;
  }
  
  vector<int>rr;
  for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
      rr.push_back(as[i]);
  return rr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing in C++, use C++ features instead of C-style string manipulation.  You can combine [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) into a very short solution.  (Also note that you should take the argument by const reference since you do not modify it.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> parseInts(std::string const & str) {
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::istringstream src{str};
    std::string buf;
    
    while (std::getline(src, buf, ',')) {
        // Note no error checking on this conversion -- exercise for the reader.
        values.push_back(std::stoi(buf));
    }
    
    return values;
}
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1630fdaebc73a33))

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't handle whitespace and inputs with more than 200 numbers.

An alternative working solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> parseInts(std::string s) {
    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ',', ' ');
    std::istringstream ss(std::move(s));
    return std::vector<int>{
        std::istream_iterator<int>{ss},
        std::istream_iterator<int>{}
    };
}

int main() {
    auto v = parseInts("1,2    , 3 ,,, 4,5,,,");
    for(auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You never really asked a question. If you are looking for an elegant method, then I provide that below. If you are asking us to debug the code, then that is a different matter.

First here is a nice utility for splitting a string

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    size_t start;
    size_t end = 0;
    while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delim, end)) != std::string::npos) {
        end = str.find(delim, start);
        strings.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

First split the string on commas:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = split(str, ',');
```

Then covert each to an int

```
std::vector<int> ints;
for (auto s : strings)
     ints.push_back(std::stoi(s))
```